# C++ how to end a thread called in a while loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two functions that run simultaneously thanks to thread, both functions write text in two separates files.

```
void Function1() {
    //Blablabla do stuff
    File1 << My stuff << std::endl;
}

void Function2() {
    //Blablabla do other stuff
    File2 << other stuff << std::endl;
}

int main {
   File1.open();
   File2.open();
   while (true){
        std::thread Th1(Function1);
        std::thread Th2(Function2);

        Th1.join();                
        Th2.join();     
        // I want to end my thread here         
        if (0x01 & GetAsyncKeyState('Q') != 0) {
            // What to put here to safely end function 1 and function 2 ?
            }
        }
    File1.close();
    File2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

How to end the thread to be able to close the files ? I am new to the use of the class Thread.

Comment: `Th1.join();` and `Th2.join();` already wait until the threads return, so they have ended by the time you reach the `if`.

Comment: `Th1.join` and `Th2.join` block until their respective threads have concluded. At the point in the program where you check for the `Q` keypress, no threads are running. You can just put a 'break;' in that code to exit the while loop. You also likely want to move your `File1.close()` and `File2.close()` to outside your `while` loop.

Comment: You mean "I want to break the loop"? If so: `break`

Comment: Also please fix your code, the braces are not matching up and you are missing `()` after `main`. Also `main` *must* have declared return type `int` in C++. `void main()` is a non-standard compiler-specific extension. Don't use it.

Comment: You are missing a close bracket, so the file close appears to be in the loop (I don't think that is what you intended).  As previously suggested, break out of the look with a break statement, and then close the files after the loop is complete.

Comment: Looks like this `while` loop is applied on wrong scope. Also `Function1` and `Function2` should have some loop which could be stopped to make this question reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

`Function1` and `Function2` aren't running when you reach the `if`; you've already `join`ed their threads, so they're done. If you just want to end the infinite loop (preventing the launching of more threads), use `break`:

```
    if (0x01 & GetAsyncKeyState('Q') != 0) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you !That is what I was doing but I get a "Acces Violation error" message. Though it is possible that it comes from a dll I use in function1.